# creating multi threaded windows service

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, windows-services

I need guidance in creating a Multi Threaded Windows Service.
The Service needs to read records from a database Table and saves it to
another service(ServiceB). The table might contain thousands of records which
the service needs to read 100 at a time and do something and saves
it to ServiceB and again take another 100 records from the table
and process it and saves it to Service B. And the process should continue
like that till it finishes all the records.

At the same time this service will get the results from ServiceB.
and update the table with the result from ServiceB.
So this service needs to do two thing simultaneously.
Any idea what is the best method to do it or any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not very specific. Could you clarify what kind of guidance you need? How to create threads? How to access DB? How to do interthread synchronization?

Comment: I want to know how to create multi threading and adding timer events.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check about Thread. Microsoft has a good [Tutorial for Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).